# Using global variables in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I'm trying to learn RequireJS and I'm a bit confused about loading global variables. I have an external script that checks to see if `window.Foo` has been instantiated. Which mean I need to instantiate it before I *require(//url/to/external-script)* the said external script

My problem is that I'm not sure how I instantiate it in requireJS

do I `define()` in a separate file then load that file before I load the external script?

do I create it in the `requirejs.config`

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are not instantiated in `requirejs.config`. There are basically two ways to do it.

You can use a `script` element and put the instantiation inline or in an external script, so long as this `script` element appears *before* the one that kicks off your module loading. So:

```
<script>
    window.Foo = ... whatever;
</script>
```

The other way is to use a RequireJS module to perform the work, lets say it is called `foo-config`:

```
define(function () {
    window.Foo = ... whatever;
});
```

And then your module that needs to have `window.Foo` defined **must have the above module among its dependencies**. This can be problematic if you are using a 3rd party module which itself uses `define` to define itself as an AMD module because there is no mechanism by which you can just *add* dependencies to such module. You can use a nested `require`:

```
require(['foo-config'], function () {
    require(['third-party']);
});
```

but this is ugly, and error prone. If you have multiple pages on which you use `third-party`, you need to always remember to use a nested `require` to load it.

On the other hand, if that 3rd party module is not AMD-ready and consequently you use a `shim` configuration to load it, then you can add your module to the list of dependencies there.

```
shim: {
     'third-party': ['foo-config'];
}
```